# Can Netty's buffer and common modules be used in android

Tags: java, android, netty

I have a server(called **A**) running on a custom protocol built with Erlang. To reach A from another server(called **B**) written in java, I wrote a TCP client library(called **C**) speaking the protocol using the beautiful Netty library. However, I have another use case, Server A, should also be reach by client applications running on android. In library **C**, I have the protocol parsing abstraction built using Netty's **netty-buffer.jar (4.1.15)** and **netty-common.jar (4.1.15)** only. My question is, can I used that same abstraction in the android client code? Working with Netty's ByteBuff is far more lifesaving the Java's ByteBuffer. I know that android runs on the Dalvik VM which is different in some aspect from the normal java JVM . 
 
The min supported android API is 16 (If it matters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's fine to use Netty in Android. Use ProGuard to make sure you only bring in the parts you need.

Android doesn't necessarily run on Dalvik anymore. There's also [ART](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/).